# Setting EntityState = Unchanged once, does not track for all objects which are the same

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following objects: Most properties removed.

```
public class WorkQueue : IEntity
{
    public WorkQueue()
    {

    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Action> Actions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> AllowableRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Role: IEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Action> Actions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WorkQueue> AllowedWorkQueues { get; set; }
}

public class Action: IEntity
{
    public Action()
    {
        Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public virtual Guid WorkQueue_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual WorkQueue WorkQueue { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

The `AllowableRoles` is a combined list of `Role` objects contained in each `Action` of the `Actions` collection of the `WorkQueue`.

When I loop through `AllowableRoles` and set each of Role's `EntityState` to `Unchanged`, I still get a duplicate record inserted into the Roles table when creating the `WorkQueue` object.

Why is this happening?

Please also refer to my previous post for a more in detailed post, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039273/cannot-insert-into-many-to-many-relationship-table-without-duplicating-records)

Comment: The only way to prevent duplicated is to make the field a primary key.  When using a primary key you have to use update (not insert) to change value.

Comment: The fields are primary keys.  I do not want to update roles, only create a new WorkQueue, and map roles (already defined in db) to it...

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first

Comment: @jdweng I don't think you seem to understand the question.

Comment: I'm looking at your previous posting.  The lines between the table aren't lining up.  For example the line between WorkQueue and Action should be between the properties "id".  The tables ActionRole and AlllowableRolesByWorkQueus should be joined by RoleId.

Comment: Not the problem. Solved it, will post my answer later.